# NestedScrollView issue, throwing error when switching between two screens

Tags: android, flutter, dart, nestedscrollview

I have some problems with NestedScrollView. I have implemented PageView with BottomNavigationBar and sometimes, when I am switch between two screens, I got this error:

'package:flutter/src/widgets/nested_scroll_view.dart': Failed assertion: line 501 pos 14:  'position.minScrollExtent != null && position.pixels != null': is not true.

[image]

```
child: NestedScrollView(
      controller: _controller,
      headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
        return <Widget>[
          SliverAppBar(
            automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
            pinned: true,
            expandedHeight: 140.0,
            floating: false,
            centerTitle: true,
            flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
              centerTitle: true,
              background: new Container(
                child: FutureBuilder(
                  future: CoverImagesApi().getImageFile(1),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if(snapshot.data != null) {
                      return Container(
                        child: Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Expanded(
                              flex: 5,
                              child: Container(
                                alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                              ),
                            ),
                            Expanded(
                              flex: 2,
                              child: new Container(
                                child: Center(
                                child: Text('Obecná tabuľa',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 26.0,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                                  ),
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                ),
                                ),
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 0.8)
                                ),
                                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter, //variable above
                              )
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                          image: new DecorationImage(
                            fit: BoxFit.cover
                            image: snapshot.data.existsSync() ? Image.file(snapshot.data).image : AssetImage('assets/tabula.jpg'),
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    } else {
                      return Container(height: 0.0, width: 0.0);
                    }
                  }
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ];

      },
      body: DataFiller(scaffoldKey: _scaffoldKey),
    )
```

Has someone any ideas?

Comment: Can you also paste the contents of DataFiller?

Comment: try adding `extendBody: true,` to the scaffold

Comment: I copied your code (minus the images and `FutureBuilder`, and replaced `DataFiller` with a `TabBarView`), and I didn't see any error. You're going to have to show more code or provide a simpler example.

Comment: @kamzik Are you able to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I was using extendBody : true, inside scaffold and was getting the same error. On removing it the error got resolved.

Comment: extendBody: true is required for my case. Is there any other solution? Let me know . Thanks.

Comment: I don't have any other solution as of now, but will update here If I find anything. Also if you can give me a reproducible sample for your code I will be able to test easily

Answer (score 2):

Just add `key: UniqueKey()` to NestedScrollView.

your code will be

```
child: NestedScrollView(
  key: UniqueKey()
  controller: _controller,
  headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
    return <Widget>[
      SliverAppBar(
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        pinned: true,
        expandedHeight: 140.0,
        floating: false,
        centerTitle: true,
        flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          background: new Container(
            child: FutureBuilder(
              future: CoverImagesApi().getImageFile(1),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if(snapshot.data != null) {
                  return Container(
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Expanded(
                          flex: 5,
                          child: Container(
                            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          flex: 2,
                          child: new Container(
                            child: Center(
                            child: Text('Obecná tabuľa',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 26.0,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                              ),
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            ),
                            ),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 0.8)
                            ),
                            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter, //variable above
                          )
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                      image: new DecorationImage(
                        fit: BoxFit.cover
                        image: snapshot.data.existsSync() ? Image.file(snapshot.data).image : AssetImage('assets/tabula.jpg'),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                } else {
                  return Container(height: 0.0, width: 0.0);
                }
              }
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ];

  },
  body: DataFiller(scaffoldKey: _scaffoldKey),
)
```

Comment: every time data is reloading every time when I scroll up and down. How to restrict it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in that, just a hot-restart is good to fix the problem. This is because hot-reload doesn't change the state of the app and you did an action that `draws from state` that isn't there(It assumes it's there)..

If all else fail, try cleaning your app and that should be good

Answer (score 0):

I have `TabView` with 4 tabs. In 2 of them I had `ScrollController` for `ListView` but 2 other didn't have `ScrollController` but had `Grid`. What helped me was adding `ScrollController` to those `Grid`s. Maybe this advice will help someone just add `ScrollController` where they are missing.

Answer (score 0):

You can try wrapping your widget with `PrimaryScrollController` and assign it a ScrollController, it fixes the `position is _NestedScrollPosition not true` problem.